# Как получить позицию слова в строке

Tags: c++, qt, строки

У меня есть строка: "Привет, одолжишь мне свою книгу? Хочу купить себе эти книги!". Есть ли встроенная функция, чтобы определить позицию слова в строке? Если нет, то как возможно получить позицию слова "книгу" в этой строке?

Answer (score 1):

С++ - значит, `string`.

`string` - значит, [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) :)

Если `char*` в духе C - см. [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)

Answer (score 1):

Если `Qt` то:

```
QString str { "Привет, одолжишь мне свою книгу? Хочу купить себе эти книги! "};
int pos { str.indexOf("книгу") };
if(pos != -1)
    qDebug() << "Позиция" << pos;
else
    qDebug() << "Нету таких";
```